# How to get album using example.php, facebook.php and base_facebook.php of facebook-php-sdk

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

in the facebook-php-sdk there is an example.php file when we can get our personal information easily doing:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

of course I get:

```
 Array ( [data] => Array (
```

and all my personal data, that is ok. But when i do

```
$facebook->api('/me/albums');
```

i get:

```
Array ( [data] => Array
(
)

)
```

and nothing more. What is failing? Its curious because when I try to get my albums using:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums

it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What permissions did you accept for the access token?
You may be missing: `user_photos`

You can check your access token using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to see what permissions is has.